# GKE kubernetes webhook support

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

GKE supports webhook?
Is it possible to setup it with these settings:

kubelet:

--authentication-token-webhook
  --authorization-mode=Webhook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, GKE does not allow customizing the API server options.